# how to get AzSql Database Import/Export Status using Python

Tags: python, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-api-management, bacpac

I am trying to import a bacpac to azure sql database it runs for almost 2.5 hours, I need to get the status of this import job i.e. in-progress, complete etc using python.
I know I can do it using Get-AzSqlDatabaseImportExportStatus -OperationstatusLink in powershell, but I want to do this using python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's `subprocess` module to run Powershell commands.

> The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to
> their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes.

You can store the Powershell script in any file and then read that file using `subprocess.Popen` method.

Example:

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
              "C:\\Project\\downloadSharePointFile.ps1"], 
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

Refer: [Running Powershell script with Python](https://data-geek.medium.com/running-powershell-script-with-python-53a908da7d34), [Executing PowerShell from Python](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/executing-powershell-from-python/#:%7E:text=Here%20is%20the%20complete%20file,run(hello_command)%20if%20hello_info.)